# Reload page dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, reload

I create a dashboard to which I added a modal box which proposes to save or to go back. To go back, I need to reload the page (so that the data will return to the initial state). I used javascript and this script works but the problem is that the browser shows that the page is reloaded (I would like to reload the page dynamically). Do you have an idea to reload the page dynamically?

current code:

```
function cancel() {
close();
document.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: "browser shows that the page is reloaded" - what do you mean ?

Comment: try `location.reload(true)`

Comment: Does `close()` refer to `window.close()`?

Comment: "browser shows that the page is reloaded"  -> https://zupimages.net/up/21/17/ptqa.png -> there are a animation when the page is reload.

I have try reload(true) but there is always animation  Royi Namir.

close() don't refer to window.close() (it's juste a fonction for edit the display of a html element to none.  JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this automatically. You will have to fetch all your values asynchronous and repopulate your Html.

Or perhaps put your entire dashboard inside an iframe and call `document.location.reload();` inside that.
That *should* stop the browser showing the reload animation. I have not tried it  though.